# Change Resource file at runtime in different class library project in same solution in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, class-library

I have a solution with these projects:

1.*Clinica* (Type is Windows Application),(`MainWindow.xaml` is here)

2.*Ferhad.Wpf.Core* (Type is Class Library), (There are three files: `Resources.xaml`, `OrangeResource.xaml`, `BlueResource.xaml`)

The `Resources.xaml` looks like that:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Ferhad.Wpf.Core;component/BlueResource.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now, from `MainWindow.xaml.cs`  I want to clear and add `OrangeReource.xaml` to `Resources.xaml`.

How can i do that:
So far I have tried this:

```
string fileName = "pack://application:,,,/Ferhad.Wpf.Core;component/OrangeReSource.xaml";
if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        ResourceDictionary dic = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(fs);

        string fileNameR = "pack://application:,,,/Ferhad.Wpf.Core;component/Resources.xaml";
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileNameR))
        {
            using (FileStream fsR = new FileStream(fileNameR, FileMode.Open))
            {
                ResourceDictionary dicR = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(fsR);
                dicR.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
                dicR.MergedDictionaries.Add(dic);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the job like that:

```
  var rDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
  rDictionary.Source = new Uri(string.Format("pack://application:,,,/Ferhad.Wpf.SystemStyles;component/OStyles.xaml"), UriKind.Absolute);
  this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rDictionary);
```